# Main differences between Node.js for Windows and Node.js for Mac OS?

Tags: node.js, macos

I'm typical .NET developer (C# is my first language), who moved to the ASP.NET MVC a few year ago.
Now is new time for significant changes in my career. If we look at the landscape of web development, we can see how the new technologies taking over the world, and in the center is the NodeJs. I still think that ASP.NET Web API is a good choice for "back end". But for some modern "front end"s better clear SPA application, without rendering on server side.
I'm trying AngularJS, NPM, Bower, Grunt and very happy.

But I'm working on Windows. And recently tried to run Node.js on Mac OS.
On Windows I have problems with install packages - sometimes , during install package, code doesn't release locks or postinstall script  newer ends. Oh…
But on Mac OS all packages have been installed fast and without any errors! Huh.

Please tell me work on Mac OS really is more convenient? And what main differences between Node.js for Windows and Node.js for Mac OS? At first glance, the work with Node.js on Mac  seems more stable and faster. Or I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Mac OSx is Unix based. Xcode & the OS X Command Line Tools will help you a lot in development. In Windows you have command-prompt and other Editor tool according to your need. As you are from .Net background, you might be good with envelopment environment of windows.

Working with Unix, you can read npm's `man` page. Windows doesn't have `man` instead npm will open a browser and and display HTML version of Standard help pages..

If you do `node index.js` in Unix, you can open `http://localhost:3000/` but in windows you might get firewall warning.